# Expressing a hypersurface of a variety as zero locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, projective-space

It should be obvious from the question that I am not an algebraic geometer, and so I would really appreciate an answer without using schemes or functor.

Let $V$ be an (embedded) variety in a complex projective space, and let $L \subset V$ by a subvariety of $V$ of codimension 1 in $V$.

Question: is it possible to find a homogeneous polynomial $F$ (depending on the embedding of $V$, but that's OK) such that 
$x \in V$ and $F(x)=0$ if and only if $x \in L$ ? (here $x$ is to be understood in homogeneous coordinates).

If this is false, then can it always be done using more than one $F$ 
(ie, can we always find homogeneous pol. $F_1, \ldots, F_r$ such that 
$x \in V$ and for all $i \leq r$, $F_i(x)=0$ is equivalent to $x \in L$?

I would very vaguely think so, but that would require to somehow prove that one can choose a set of generators of $I(V)$ that could be completed into a set of generators of $I(L)$ by just adding $F$, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not leaving this as an answer since I'm afraid it uses too much and Mohan's answer is perfect, but I think it's great motivation for learning about divisors. See Chapter II, Example 6.6.3 in Hartshorne. The setup is that every codimension $1$ thing in $Q = \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$ has some "type" $(a,b)$. If I embed $Q$ as a quadric surface in $\mathbb P^3$ via the Segre map then the hyperplane in $\mathbb P^3$ restricts to something of class $(1,1)$. It follows that I can only get things in $Q$ of type $(d,d)$ by intersecting with hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, the answer is no and for the latter the answer is yes and your vague feeling is correct.

Let me give you a simple example to illustrate why the first is false. Take $V$ to be the quadric defined by $xy-zw=0$ in projective 3-space. Take $L$ to be a line, say given by $x=z=0$ contained in $V$. One can prove (and not difficult) that there is no single homogeneous polynomial in $x,y,z,w$ satisfying your requirement.

Comment: thank you for your answer. sorry if the second question was a bit dumb, I guess I am rusty on ideal theory. I guess you would just start with a generating set for I(V) and keep adding elements of I(L) and invoke noetherianity to say that the procedure will eventually stop?